# How to call a stored procedure dynamically?

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
FOR rec IN ( SELECT Procedure_Name 
                 FROM DATAMART_PROCESS_STEPS
                 ORDER BY Procedure_Order )
LOOP
  EXECUTE rec;
END LOOP;
```

I have a procedure that manages a series of procedures from table `DATAMART_PROCESS_STEPS`, and I need to run every procedure within this table dynamically. Oracle SQL Developer does not like the way I am executing procedures; it throws syntax error. What is the proper way to achieve this task?

```
EXECUTE 'BEGIN ' || rec || '; END';
```

I have also tried this after reading through tutorial on stored procedures, but it has issue with single quotes. Help. If you need more detail or code please just ask.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What error Oracle throws? Copy the error to clipboard and do a [web search](http://google.com/search?q=your-error-comes-here). See the reasons for the error and try provided solutions. If you don't find a solution then [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: @student Thank you for advice, but I have already done as you suggested; "Encountered the symbol rec when expect ... ect". It thinks I should := instead. Web search was no help.

Comment: Have you tried using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ?

Comment: @PZNevill I feel that your syntax is correct. Does `rec` contain single quotes?

Comment: @student I agree. It seems like it should run fine, but it doesn't recognize as variable.

Comment: @Mihai-DanielVirna This solved syntax error problem. Why would I need immediate though?

Comment: @PZNevill - [`execute`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve022.htm#sthref1583) is a SQL\*Plus/SQL Developer shorthand for an anonymous PL/SQL block. It isn't valid inside other PL/SQL. Dynamic calls within PL/SQL use [`execute immediate`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/executeimmediate_statement.htm), which is unrelated to plain `execute`, and as the syntax diagram shows the `immediate` is not optional.

Comment: @AlexPoole That was very informative. Being new to PL/SQL I was unaware of EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`execute` command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve022.htm) is SQL*Plus/SQL Developer shorthand for an anonymous PL/SQL block. It isn't valid inside other PL/SQL, including inside your master procedure.

Dynamic calls within PL/SQL use the unrelated [`execute immediate` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/executeimmediate_statement.htm), and as the syntax diagram shows the immediate keyword is not optional.

[image: execute immediate syntax diagram]

The dynamic SQL statement in this case needs to be an anonymous PL/SQL block around your cursor-supplied procedure name, as you've already realised. But your second version is missing a semicolon after the `END` you're concatenating onto the string; and you're referring to `rec` directly rather than the column within that record type, i.e. using the name of the column your cursor is selecting.

So your loop needs to do:

```
FOR rec IN ( SELECT Procedure_Name 
                 FROM DATAMART_PROCESS_STEPS
                 ORDER BY Procedure_Order )
LOOP
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN ' || rec.procedure_name || '; END;';
END LOOP;
```